# iOS Secure Configuration Parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, plist

Is a plist compiled into the actual binary of an iOS application? Specifically, I'm curious if it is a safe place to store configuration parameters that are sensitive (API keys, etc.).

Comment: I Think this question fits http://security.stackexchange.com better than SO.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very safe place. Plist file is not compiled into the app binary. iOS application (myapplication.app) seems to be like a folder which contains the executable binary and all the resources (info.plist too) as a separated files.

Comment: That is what I feared. So a .h is probably safer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid storing sensitive data in plists, as it quite easy to get information from a plist.

Read further in 
http://support.aviary.com/knowledgebase/articles/294869-ios-where-to-add-your-api-key
and
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1